# Wordpress shows me a worng url and does not load a theme or css

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, themes

I have sever problems with my local installations of websites. I am trying to restore it but have difficulties.
I deleted and reinstalled MAMP PRO.
I created a host to no avail
The default "localhost" was working fine. For test purposes I placed my files overthere.

Instead of showing the theme (with css loaded) I get a page with just the homepage content.

When I try to access the dashboard it shows me a 404 (again without theme and css)

The outputted url starts with this:

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/localhost/wp-login.php?redirect_to
```

Notice the second localhost in it.

Does anyone knows why this is and what I can do?

It happens also with other local hosted domains.

BTW I migrated the database from my online server with an export of all the tables and imported it in the local database. I changed the first two options in de options table to 'localhost' with phpMyAdmin.
Really don't know wat to do next I'm struggling with it for three days now.

Comment: Questions regarding server administration should be posted to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I notice one thing, you replaced url with only localhost?

you were suppose to replace localhost with directory for siteurl and home.

See the screenshot:

[image]

See how I added http://localhost/marina

One more thing its not only first two rows. sometime rows go down and up. Look for siteurl and home in option_name to replace the value.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out an entry in the database was corrupted.
A theme_mod_abcd_child entry was causing the troubles. Restoring that entry from a backup did the trick.

BTW I don't understand why I have to loose points over this question. IMO it is a legitimate one......

Comment: You don't have to lose points, you could have deleted the question. And you still could.